# Why my text extrude borders but not front?

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to make some 3D text. I'm following a tutorial but the extrution is of the borders of the text not the front or the back. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Fill mode is set to "none". Setting it to "both" should fix your problem.